# Creating a Nested Dictionary from 2 Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries that I created and need to now try to combine those. I have searched for days now try to find something similar to this but the examples I see aren't quite doing what I am looking for and/or are not working for me and I don't know what I may be missing or if something is wrong with my dictionaries. Can I get some advice?

Examples of the dics I have:

```
pro_go: {
    Q9Y7X7 : ['GO:0003674','GO:0005829'...],  
    'Q9Y819': ['GO:0008150','GO:0005794',...]...
}
go_def: {
    'GO:0010332': 'response to gamma radiation', 
    'GO:0010337': 'cellulose synthase', ...
}
```

What I need to continue on with my project:

```
pro_go_def: {
    Q9Y7X7: {
        'GO:xxxxxx': response, 
        'GO:xxxxxx': metabolism...
    }, 
    Q9Y819:{
        'GO:xxxxx': cell wall, 
        'GO:xxxxx': 'transporter activity',
    } ....
}
```

So I need a dictionary
pro_go key , pro_go value=go_def key, go_def value

I have to keep it basic and not use any other packages(?) like panda or collections that I seen in some of the examples. And I'd love any explanations that you may give , I really want to understand whats going on and really am lost with Python at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
pro_go_def = {
    k: {elem: go_def[elem] for elem in v if elem in go_def}
    for k, v in pro_go.items()
}
```

Comment: I think that might do it for me. I tried to take your compression and change it to for loops because I need to put a try in there because not all of the proteins have a GO and it is tossing a KeyError. I am failing at dict comprehension also. Could you possibly break it out for me? I'd be ever so grateful.

Comment: it worked perfectly.  You are saving me from more hair pulling and stress. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import ChainMap

dict1 = {'name': 'Jack', 'age':22} 
dict2 = {'gender':'male'}

dict_common = ChainMap(dict1,dict2)



 for i in dict_common.keys():
        print(i)
```

**Result**

> gender
> name
> age